Cannot use a \toprule inside a \longtblr
When trying to use a command I have defined inside a longtblr gives the following error:
20: Misplaced \noalign. \end
20: Missing } inserted. \end
20: Missing \endgroup inserted. \end
20: Missing } inserted. \end
20: Missing \endgroup inserted. \end
20: Missing \endgroup inserted. \end
20: Missing } inserted. \end
20: Undefined control sequence. \end
20: Too many }'s. \end
20: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Extra \endgroup. \end
20: Extra \endgroup. \end
20: Too many }'s. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing = inserted for \ifdim. \end
20: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
20: You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing = inserted for \ifdim. \end
20: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
20: You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode. \end
20: Extra \endcsname. \end
20: Extra \endcsname. \end
20: Extra \endcsname. \end
20: Extra \endcsname. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Argument of \XC@split@iv has an extra }. \end
20: Paragraph ended before \XC@split@iv was complete. \end
20: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
20: Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \end
20: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end
20: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
20: Missing font identifier. \end
: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
: Command \underbar has changed.
: Command \underline has changed.
20: Overfull \hbox (12.72903pt too wide) in paragraph

Why is this? It works in a normal table.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{comment} % Comment
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln} % add hash line for tables
\usepackage{booktabs} % new tables
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title},
  label = {tab:test},
  ]{
  colspec = {|c|c|c|c|},
  rowhead = 1,
  %hlines,
  %row{even} = {gray9},
  %row{1} = {olive9},
  }
  \toprule
  ABD & ABD & {ABD} & {ABD} \\
  ABD & ABD & {ABD} & {ABD} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}



I don't think that has anything to do with the newcommands, try removing  \refsec{ABD} and \refpage{ABD} you seem to get the same error

If you use rowhead=1, your table must have more than one row.

Yes @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, adding another row or commenting rowhead=1 resolves the issue.

Okay so there was a couple of things going on here, I did try with multiple rows and reduced to to one for the MWE, so you are correct adding a row fixes this example. But when I try paste my full table in which contains \toprule its breaks again, in a different way...

@lukygee Please update your question so that it reproduces your actual problem.

Please don't post just code fragments. Always make a small, but compilable test file

If I combine your new code fragment with the preamble from your previous version, it compiles without error.

Sorry, not sure where the preamble went, added back now

Your code compiles without error for me. Can you show your complete .log file so we see which package versions you have?

The excerpt of the log file you show, does not seem to be from the code in the question.

It compiles without error when I remove the \toprule from the longtblr. The error (line 20) is on the \end{longtblr}. I must have some command that is changing something, let me see if I can track it down

Indeed with my full preable it no longer works

I have added the full preamble and will slowly remove lines until I find the error

While your full preamble loads every package but the kitchen sink (some of them multiple times), it does not load \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

The M in MWE means minimal, are you really saying you need all that to show your problem? why inputenc twice (you don't need it at all) why longtable twice (when you are using tabularray not longtable  why hyperref twice?  please try to post more reasonable examples.  You have 200 lines here almost none of them related to your question.

I see, and what does that do? Where should it go? And a the preamble is a bit of a mess

Made more M, unfortunately when it is something in the preamble causing the issue, It's hard to know which

@lukygee you can add that anywhere after you have loaded tabularray (see its documentation) but in general you should start every document with an empty preamble and only add packages as you use them, this looks like random packages just copied in for no reason.

@lukygee See the first version of your question to see where to place the missing library https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/720768/1

the preamble is not "a bit of a mess", it is a complete mess. Spent an hour to clean them up.

@lukygee no, it really is not hard, but you make it much harder for anyone trying to trace the problem if you include100s of unrelated packages. You can easily test before posting that the problem still shows if you remove inputenc which you still list twice. and why are you loading xcolor and arydshln and longtable in an example that does not use any of those?

Well more is more huh? ;) Fixed, thanks guys. I will take some time tidying my preamble.

Your MWE is still far from Minimal it is loading multiple packages that you are not using.

For use booktabs rules in tabularray tables you need to load booktabs library which adopt it for works in them. For example, MWE, on basis of your code example, should be:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} % <---
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title},
  label = {tab:test},
                ]{vlines,
                  colspec = {*{4}{c}},
                  rowhead = 1,
                 }
  \toprule
  ABD & ABD & {ABD} & {ABD} \\
  ABD & ABD & {ABD} & {ABD} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


Edit:
Another way to draw your table is to remove vertical lines by deleting vlines option in table specification, as suggest @Teepeemm in his comment, and by this gives to table more professional look:


booktabs would have a comment about your use of vlines.

@Teepeemm, you are right. I added brief explanation about this tabularray features.

Actually, I meant that booktabs would say you should remove vlines.
